# Remove all the elements outside of a container?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to find a way to remove all the elements (div's) outside of a specific container.

For example:

I have an HTML container with a few div's inside of it like so:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="baby"></div>
    <div class="baby"></div>
    <div class="baby"></div>
    <div class="baby"></div>
</div>
<div id="someID">
    <div class="baby"></div>
    <div class="baby"></div>
    <div class="baby"></div>
</div>
<div class="baby"></div>
<div class="baby"></div>
<div class="baby"></div>
```

I basically need to remove all the elements with the class name `baby` that is outside of `container`. Some of the elements don't even have a container so I cannot target them using the parent or anything like that.

Is this possible at all?

Comment: We (all humans) are outside of that container. Take care of us! Don't remove us!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use **[`:not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)** or **[`not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not/)** to avoid the element inside `#container`

```js
$('.baby:not(#container .baby)').remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div class="baby">1</div>
  <div class="baby">1</div>
  <div class="baby">1</div>
  <div class="baby">1</div>
</div>
<div id="someID">
  <div class="baby">2</div>
  <div class="baby">2</div>
  <div class="baby">2</div>
</div>
<div class="baby">3</div>
<div class="baby">3</div>
<div class="baby">3</div>
```

---

Using **[`not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not/)**

```js
$('.baby').not('#container .baby').remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div class="baby">1</div>
  <div class="baby">1</div>
  <div class="baby">1</div>
  <div class="baby">1</div>
</div>
<div id="someID">
  <div class="baby">2</div>
  <div class="baby">2</div>
  <div class="baby">2</div>
</div>
<div class="baby">3</div>
<div class="baby">3</div>
<div class="baby">3</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

```js
//$('.baby:not(#container .baby)').remove();//select class baby not inside container using selector :not

$('.baby').not('#container .baby').remove();//select class baby not inside container using method .not()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
<div class="baby">1</div>
<div class="baby">2</div>
<div class="baby">3</div>
<div class="baby">4</div>
</div>

<div id="someID">
<div class="baby">5</div>
<div class="baby">6</div>
<div class="baby">7</div>
</div>


<div class="baby">8</div>
<div class="baby">9</div>
<div class="baby">0</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also use the container where all the children are located such as:

```
$('body').children().not('#container').remove();
```